# Front Panel Audio Not Working

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, microphone, audio-jack

My rear audio ports work fine, but my front panel audio jacks are acting up.

At first, neither functioned at all, but I was able to achieve some limited results in `alsamixer`. When I unmuted my front microphone by pressing `M`, Audacity was able to receive audio properly from `default: Front Mic:0`; however, it still does not show up in the Ubuntu Sound GUI.

My front headphone jack is still almost completely nonfunctional, but when I unmute `Front Mic` and `Headphone` in `alsamixer`, I can hear everything being picked up by the front microphone, but nothing else, and the headphone jack is also unrecognized by the Sound GUI. I have tried outputting to every speaker port detected by Audacity (which has the most options of any program I have found so far), but the front panel headphone jack produced no sound with any of the options.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a home-built tower, and my motherboard is an ASRock 980DE3/U3S3 ATX with an FX 8350 CPU.

**EDIT:** My front microphone is working properly after a restart, but my headphone jack is only outputting audio through the right ear, and in order to hear anything at all, both the left and right channels must be unmuted in `alsamixer`. All of the panning controls are set to center.

How can I debug/fix this?